# SQL Server 2008 vs Visual Studio 2010 Express version of SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-express

I'd like to know what are the benefits of using Sql Server 2008 over the version that is installed default with visual studio 2010 express (I think its Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2).

As far as I know, it is possible to create applications using MDF database files with visual studio, and the applications work just fine; and there doesn't seem to be a GUI to manage the databases (unless the ones that are integrated in VB.NET etc.)

In what cases would I need to use a non compact version of SQL Server?

Comment: in your tags you put a bit of everything, you confuse compact framework with sql compact...

Comment: http://www.ehow.com/facts_6960501_comparison-microsoft-sql-server-versions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compact lacks some of the features of the normal SQL Server:

- Procedural T-SQL - Select Case, If, features
- Distributed transactions
- Native XML, XQuery/QPath
- **Stored procedures, views, triggers**
- Role-based security
- Number of concurrent connections is up to 256
- Database size support up to 4GB (express is 10GB now I believe)

On the other hand compact supports non-admin installation option and it is hosted in your application process.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio installs SQL Server Express, which is a full blown SQL server engine. SQL Server Compact is an embedded database library. It's pretty close to SQL Server Standard Edition and is suitable for almost anything you would need.

Comment: +1. The question will basically boil down to comparing the SKUs (Express vs. Standard/Enterprise/etc). This has nothing to do with Compact.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server compact edition is an inprocess/embedded database; it will be executed directly inside your process and will allow you to deal with the datasource with zero deployment pain.

SQL Server ( all versions including Express and excluding compact ) needs to be installed on a specific server so you need at least the hardware and somebody who sets it up, then you can have all applications you want connecting to it to read/write data.

we can also summarize that SQL Compact is a DBMS but not a RDBMS.

Comment: Actually, Compact is a RDBMS, it supports tables and keys and relationships between those tables. What's lacking (among other things) is stored procedures.

Comment: @Davide: you're saying Compact isn't relational?

Comment: DBMS / RDBMS ? Can you define this please? Database Management System / Relational DataBase Management System?

Comment: ooops, I confused, my fault sorry!! I was thinking the R of RDMBMS was for Remote! of course is there for Rational and my answer was wrong... will fix it soon. sorry :DDDD

Comment: R is Relational and not Rational

Answer (score 0):

Limitations of the SQL Server Compact: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc835494%28SQL.100%29.aspx